# Macbook crashed, need help finding out why

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, crash

I was running Football Manager 2020 with Spotify playing in the background and Firefox was running as well.

Mac suddenly crashed (cursor doesn't move) and audio starts looping – went on for a good 5-10 seconds? Then it shuts down by itself, and the fan ramped up to full speed for a second after it shut down.

Chain of events: cursor/visual stuck - audio loop - display turns to black - fan full speed - fan stops - Mac restarts.

Upon restart, Firefox has logged me out of all my accounts, but not Spotify or Steam client. Was Firefox the reason? I copied the crash report too if anyone could have a look and translate what it all means (can I post on here?) – I hope it's not overheating? I played Football Manager 2020 for some time now on my Mac and this was the first time it crashed, and usually I see the temperature runs on average 55-70c while on it.

Cheers

Macbook Pro 2020 13" i5

Comment: You should open `Console` app and check `Crash Reports` in the sidebar on the left. Hopefully you should find a crash report for one of the applications that were running at the time. Unfortunately, I don't know how to read them in depthly but maybe someone else here could help :)

Comment: Do you know if this is repeatable? Have you tried running with the exact same setup?

Comment: Please share your crash report (via https://www.PasteBin.com or otherwise) and we’ll take a look.

Comment: Crash Reports in Console doesn't show the exact crash that happened here, weirdly. And I have not tried repeating it, kinda worried – only machine I have at uni right now.

Here's the [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/bjWxvjiz), do check please!

I've also ran a diagnostics test and it reported no problem.

Comment: Not sure if commenting without tagging notifies previous commenters? I'm tagging @pion here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801742595f): "compressed PTE 0xfffffe818487a938 0xc010000000000000 has extra bits 0x8000000000000000`

Your system was under memory pressure and the virtual memory subsystem started compressing memory. At some point, one of the compressed page table entries (PTEs) became corrupted. The kernel attempted to repair this corruption but was unable and so it rightly induced a panic rather than allowing the OS to continue running in an inconsistent state.

Memory corruption can happen for a great deal of reasons, including software bugs, hardware bugs, and even cosmic rays occasionally knocking out enough electrons in your DRAM to flip a bit. In order to further debug corruption, we would need to have a core dump from the time of failure. Short of that, there’s no way to begin to discern between the above three possibilities.

What this means for you is: Don’t worry about it too much if this is a one-off event. If, however, you begin to see panics and hangs more regularly (especially if you try repeating the same workload) then that is good data to collect.

(All that being said: Make sure that you always maintain an ongoing backup of your data. While rare, memory corruption can indicate an incipient hardware failure that may render your machine unusable. Computers are never to be fully trusted.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. If by core dump you mean by checking the Console app, there wasn't any in there weirdly enough – could the memory pressure happen because of Football Manager 2020? Since the Iris GPU runs on the same RAM? Also find it weird that Firefox logged out all of my accounts online.

Comment: No. A core dump is a large binary file that records the entire contents of the kernel’s address space at the time it’s captured. It’s not stored by default as it takes time and space to capture and can contain sensitive information (such as passwords). Memory pressure is normal; it just means you’re doing a lot of stuff and you’re running out of physical memory to do it in. Playing games on an integrated GPU (also suggesting a lower-end system with probably not a lot of RAM) can certainly do it.

Comment: @isaac-k Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes-siree. Forgot to mark it as answered. Updated

Comment: Hey @pion, just wondering if you could have a look at my new crash paste bin report? It just crashed again. Left it to sleep (closed the lid) while it was on a screensaver. No external monitor, or USB attached to my Mac. It wasn't charging too. Hope you don't mind? (https://pastebin.com/HVbYUG0Q). Cheers

Comment: @isaac-k This is an entirely different and unrelated panic. Your trackpad driver hung when the system tried to power it down on the way to sleep. It's ultimately an Apple bug. If it happens again feel free to post a new question. While there's always a chance that memory corruption can be implicated in both of these panics and warrants further debugging, we should rule out more deterministic scenarios first.

Comment: (I should specify that it is your *external* [Magic] trackpad, specifically. So one workaround is to not use it... but that's, of course, a workaround, not a fix to the root cause.)